# lighthttpd rewrite issue

Tags: lighttpd, url-rewriting

I  want to rewrite my robots.txt for all domains but main one (I have domain aliases).  It seems that my rules conflict or override each other - for the test.example.org domain all images/css/js do not work - the robots does rewrite but nothing else works. Note that my site uses a single index.php controller.  I am unclear how to rephrase these rules.

```
url.rewrite-once = (
  "^(.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js)$" => "$1.$2",   # Cache-busing js and css files
    "^/favicon\.(.*)" => "/images/favicon/favicon.ico",
    "^/css/.+" => "$0", # directories with static files
    "^/js/.+" => "$0",
    "^/htc/.+" => "$0",
    "^/favicon\.ico$" => "$0", # static file example
    "^/robots.txt" => "$0",
    "^/(.*)\.php(.*)" => "$0",
    "^/(.+)$" => "/index.php/$1"
)


$HTTP["host"] == "test.example.org" {
   # url.rewrite-repeat = ("^/robots\.txt$" => "altbots.txt")
}
```

Edit: To clarify... I have 2 domains - example.org and test.example.org. They are aliases of each other - i.e. they point to the exact same site. I want the 10 or so rules defined at top to work for both domains. But for test.example.org I want to use a different robots file. I thought that the above would work but uncommenting the test.example.org line for robots causes all the previous 10ish rules to no longer work. And that's what I don't understand - why does adding that line:

```
url.rewrite-repeat = ("^/robots\.txt$" => "altbots.txt")
```

cause the previous css, js, etc rules to no longer apply?

Comment: See my answer. If that's not what you want I have likely misunderstood. Perhaps you could then refine the information in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you use a negative lookahead in your regular expressions, or you use selectors.

```
# Somewhere above declare the path to the robots.txt
var.robots = "/var/www/somewhere/robots.txt"
# The selector
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/robots\.txt$" {
  alias.url                = ( "/robots.txt" => var.robots )
}
```

Now the rewrite above should be fine, as it should catch the `/robots.txt` ... however, in your particular case you still have to make sure that this URI exists. This is what the selector in my sample does ...

Of course you can also instead of using a variable simply use the literal string in its stead.